# converted vector image doesnt show correctly in corel draw

Tags: vector, corel-draw

Im having some issues converting my image to a vector image

my png
[image]

Im following [this guide](http://goinkscape.com/how-to-vectorize-in-inkscape/) which uses inkscape to convert it.

after saving I have my svg file

opening this in chrome looks good.

however when I open in corel draw I get this:

[image]

Why does it look the way it does in corel draw while chrome shows it correctly?  In the end this is a waterbottle design that Im having engraved and the engravers needs it to look right in corel draw.

[link to svg file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApXgO1jaK-Jli994M1Y6gFU3UO1VEg)

[link to zipped contents of my working folder](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApXgO1jaK-Jli997YhbCLbsKsX6u4g)

**Update1**

I have tried the below suggestions of removing the image tag, Combine the paths and Rafael's walk through.  However it is still the same issue.

I also tried to start from scratch.  this time starting and working solely inside inkscape.  Tracing each silhouette individually as opposed to the whole image. But it still does not look right

[here is the latest svg](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApXgO1jaK-Jli998yegLU73jfBQVhg), ill try to get a screenshot of what it looks like in corel shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying all suggestions and recreating the image from scratch (tracing bitmaps individually for each silhouette instead of the image as whole) there were always errors when opening it in corel draw

in the end the only thing that fixed it was to open it in illustrator then saving it (again) as an svg.  then it showed up in corel draw correctly

so inkscape seemed to be the problem

Comment: The problem was in `CorelDraw` - it is known to incorrectly import some `.svg`. I had the same problem as you, and `inkscape` helped me. I opened `.svg` in `inkscape` and saved it as `.pdf`. `CorelDraw` opened `.pdf` file with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the second image, I'd suggest that there is a stray point/vector on the upper left of the screen. The fill function is creating havoc there and also along the bottom of the screen.

If you have layers in your original, there may be the same stray points on a separate layer.

If you care to post the svg file, I'll take a look at it, as I'm sure will others.

I've downloaded the file, opened it in Inkscape, deleted the linked image as suggested. I think this part is important. I then saved the file from Inkscape under a non-conflicting filename and when opened in CorelDraw X7, the artifacts are gone.

I would have possibly attempted to locate the artifacts that caused the problem, but it was easier to solve as indicated.

Comment: edited answer to reflect successful result. I hope you can duplicate it.

Answer (score 3):

There is an PNG Image linked in the SVG with a path to a local disk:

`C:\Users\oweng\Desktop\waterbottle\waterbottle.png`

You might want to remove it and try again. I'd use a plain-text editor for this and just delete the `<image [...] />` part. SVG content is just text.

Edit: Apart from this image the paths look ok. In illustrator it also opens fine. One problem might be that there are too many points on that object (2759). Postscript 1 had a limit of 1500 points per path, so maybe Corel has some issues with that. You could try to separate some of the paths and create smaller groups in Inkscape (with Path > Break Apart and Path > Combine), so you don't have one large compound path, but several smaller ones, like the sun, the logos etc.

Comment: tried this but no luck!

Answer (score 2):

I will not answer about the importing of the image from Inkscape to Corel Draw (Corel for short). Sorry about that.

My Corel is in Spanish and I do not know the right names of the menu, but I'll post some images.

But a way to do it inside Corel the proper way.

Your image is of bad quality. Keep that in mind.

1. Import it into Corel. File > Import
2. Select it and on Bitmap choose resample it.

[image]

3. Resample it to 200%, keep aliasing on.

[image]

4. Now we are going to clean it. Effects > Adjust > Enhance Contrast

[image]

5. Move these sliders. On your image start with these values. This step will clean the JPG artifacts and make them more black-white. You can zoom in in your image and try different levels. (Probably go as far as 100-170)

[image]

6. Right Click on the image. Choose Vectorize > High-quality

Press "Keep original size" if asked.

[image]

7. Keep the default values, wait 1 second for the preview and press Accept.

[image]

8. Done. You need to tidy up a bit of the vector. If you have a better quality image you can get this done without cleaning and recoloring.

[image]

[image]

Personally, I would grab individual items, like logos from different sources, vectorize them separately and rearrange them.

Just beware of copyright issues.